# How to detect multiple handles used by the same individual?

Tags: social-network-analysis

Suppose a person (John Doe) uses different user names (handles) in different circumstances (for simplicity, let us limit the conversation to a single social network, e.g., `twitter`). E.g., he

- posts pictures of kittens as `john_doe`,
- posts political rants as `deplorable_john`,
- shares technology news as `super_doe`
- &c (and each `screen_name` has a *different* `id`, so no short cut).

**How would you go about detecting that all these accounts are used by the same individual?**

- SNA: look at who they follow (and maybe who follows them): if these sets are sufficiently similar, it's a good signal.
- NLP: compare the posted texts and try to detect that they have been written by the same author.
- Meta data: see if the accounts are usually active from the same geo location at the same time.

What other approaches have been / could be tried?

Any published work?

Comment: You'll find much published work by searching for "author(ship) recognition/attribution/verification/classification".

Comment: You can also search for "computational stylometry" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylometry